# Continues Line numbers printed all the environments

Tags: line-numbering

I am using **lineno.sty** package. I am using package in two column layout. I am using the lot environments like "Opening page mini page concept, Keybox, figures, tables, lot of user defined environments is used. But I can't get the line number output all the environments.

My requirement is **I would like to control single command like "\linenumbers" all the environments automatically print the line numbers.** Any other option is available in the lineno.sty style file or any other packages is available to create the line numbers without disturbing any environments.

My tex file coding below mentioned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\editor{Wagner L. Ara\'{u}jo, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\reviewer{Jedrzej Jakub Szymanski, Max Planck Institute of Molecular Plant Physiology, Germany }
\reviewer{Dimas Mendes Ribeiro, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\correspondence{%\protect\includegraphics{Saravana.jpg}\newline
Keith Lindsey is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology in the School of Biological and Biomedical Science sat Durham University, UK. His research interests are in understanding how genes and signaling systems regulate the development of plants. Most of his work is with the model experimental organism Arabidopsis thaliana.\newline}
\abstract{Plants are sessile organisms and therefore they must adapt their growth and architecture to a changing environment. Understanding how hormones and genes interact to coordinate plant growth in a changing environment is a major challenge in developmental biology. Although a localized auxin concentration maximum in the root tip is important for root development, auxin concentration cannot change independently of multiple interacting hormones and genes. In this review, we discuss the experimental evidence showing that the POLARIS peptide of Arabidopsis plays an important role in hormonal crosstalk and root growth, and review the crosstalk between auxin and other hormones for root growth with and without osmotic stress. Moreover, we discuss that experimental evidence showing that, in root development, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activities and hormones regulate gene expression. We further discuss how it is increasingly evident that mathematical modeling is a valuable tool for studying hormonal crosstalk. Therefore, a combined experimental and modeling study on hormonal crosstalk is important for elucidating the complexity of root development.}
\metanote{$\dagger$Joint corresponding authors}
\keywords{root development, POLARIS peptide, hormonal crosstalk, osmotic stress, kinetic modelin}
\firstpara{\section*{Introduction}
Hormone signaling systems coordinate plant growth and development through a range of com- plex interactions. The activities of hormones such as auxin, ethylene, cytokinin, abscisic acid, gibberellin, and brassinosteroids depend on cellular context and exhibit either synergistic or antagonistic interactions. Additionally, auxin is directionally transported through plant tissues, providing positional and vectorial information during development (Vanneste and Friml, 2009).\hfilneg}
\maketitle


\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum
```

My output pages below mentioned

[image: Line number does not view all the environments]

Kindly advice and provide the solution

Comment: the posted code makes multiple errors starting `! Too many }'s.
l.9 \author[1]{Junli Liu}}
                          
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \affil` Please fix to be a complete minimal document that demonstrates the problem in the question without unrelated errors.

Comment: Find attached below mentioned error fixed minimal document. Kindly provide the solution...

Comment: You can not "attach" files. Please just edit the example in the question so that it is a complete small error free document that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: not true line numbering - but perhaps the `vruler` package will help? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/vruler