# Line number problem

Tags: line-numbering

[Line number is not viewed all the environments like figures, tables, user defined environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218981/continues-line-numbers-printed-all-the-environments?noredirect=1#comment513922_218981)

Find attached below mentioned error fixing sample tex document

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\@editor{}
\def\editor#1{%
     \gdef\@editor{\raggedright \textbf{Edited by:}\newline #1}}

\def\@reviewer{}
\def\reviewer#1{%
     \gdef\@reviewer{\raggedright \textbf{Reviewed by:}\newline #1}}

\def\@metanote{}
\def\metanote#1{%
     \gdef\@metanote{\raggedright  #1}}

\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
     \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\def\@abstract{}
\def\abstract#1{%
     \gdef\@abstract{\fontsize{9.5}{11.5}\selectfont #1}}

\def\@keywords{}
\def\keywords#1{%
     \gdef\@keywords{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}}

\def\@firstpara{}
\def\firstpara#1{%
     \gdef\@firstpara{\raggedright  #1}}

\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
linecolor=black,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
theoremseparator={~|},%
frametitlerule=false,%
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
shade,left color=white, right color=black}}},
frametitlerulecolor=black,
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=6pt,
innerbottommargin=6pt,
innerleftmargin=6pt,
innerrightmargin=6pt,
frametitlebelowskip=0pt,
}



\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{keybox}{KEY CONCEPT}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\reviewer{Jedrzej Jakub Szymanski, Max Planck Institute of Molecular Plant Physiology, Germany }
\reviewer{Dimas Mendes Ribeiro, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\correspondence{Keith Lindsey is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology.}
\abstract{Plants are sessile organisms and therefore they must adapt their growth and architecture to a changing environment.}
\metanote{$\dagger$Joint corresponding authors}
\keywords{root development, POLARIS peptide, hormonal crosstalk, osmotic stress, kinetic modelin}
\firstpara{\section*{Introduction}
Hormone signaling systems coordinate plant \hfilneg}
\maketitle


\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development.


\begin{keybox}[POLARIS (PLS) peptide]
The POLARIS (PLS) peptide was identified in the plant species Arabidopsis thaliana by promoter trapping. The gene encodes a mRNA of ca. 600 bases, at the 3-end of which is a 36 amino acid open reading frame (ORF). Translation of the ORF is required for biological activity. The tran- scriptional start of the gene overlaps with the 3-UTR of an upstream gene. Expression of the PLS gene is strongest in root tips, but is also detectable in young leaves, and is induced by auxin. Mutation of POLARIS leads to several developmental defects, including a short root phenotype and reduced vascular complexity in leaves. Recent results show a role for PLS in repressing ethylene responses, and in promoting ethylene-mediated auxin biosynthesis.
\end{keybox}
\begin{align*}
          \sin A \cos B &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sin(A-B)+\sin(A+B) \right] \\
          \sin A \sin B &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sin(A-B)-\cos(A+B) \right] \\
          \cos A \cos B &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B) \right] \\
\end{align*}

\begin{figure}
\caption{DR5::GFP expression in wild type and pls mutant, showing difference in auxin gradients (upper panel), and PIN1 immunolocalization in wildtype and pls mutant, showing differences in PIN protein levels (lower panel). This ?gure is adapted with permission from the Figure 4 of Liu et al. (2010a) and the Figure 1 of Liu et al. (2013).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: This should be an edit to your original question, not a new question.  Use the edit button at the bottom of the question.